# How detailed must a description in a non-patent instance of prior art be to invalidate claims?

Tags: novelty, invalidation

Brief context

- I'm in the early stages of product development, pre-prototype.
  (Subtext: definitely no funds available for a legal opinion. I'll
  cross that bridge when it becomes feasible; for now, I'm just looking
  for a better understanding how prior art is generally interpreted in
  cases like this one.)
- Bad news: there is an active US patent that covers my concept
  (most claims are relevant and not easily designed around).
- Good news (probably): I've found a few instances of prior art that
  anticipate the patent, invalidating the relevant claims (my own
  non-lawyerly opinion of course). However, that depends on how the
  prior art is interpreted, as the patent is not a carbon copy of the
  prior art.
- The company does not appear to be practicing the patent anymore (nor
  are there any other companies doing so), so I don't see a need to go
  out of my way to invalidate it, but I'm doing a bit of homework now
  in case at some point in the future, the patent holder makes a fuss.
- (I recognize that to show invalidity you have to show "that the
  patent is invalid by clear and convincing evidence, a substantially
  greater burden" than proving infringement
  https://chicagounbound.uchicago.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5529&context=journal_articles)
- (I'll keep this post focused on an issue regarding one instance of
  prior art; I've made another post regarding a different issue
  regarding another instance of prior art.)

Rather than citing the patent or prior art here, I'll lay out the key issue in general terms; for the sake of making the discussion a bit less abstract, I'll pretend here that the patent and the prior art refer to bicycles.

- I've found a blog post (via a search on Google, i.e., the post is
  publicly accessible) dated a couple of years before the patent's
  priority date
- (Note: the blog post is not cited in the patent or its examination.)
- The blog post describes a bicycle that fits the description of the
  bicycle described in the patent's claims, apart from minor
  differences. (The most notable difference is that the bicycle in the
  blog includes an additional element not described in the bicycle in
  the patent—but the patent doesn't exclude the possibility that that
  element could be included—e.g., its claims all use the structure "a
  bicycle comprising a, b, c..." . Also, a person can still use the
  bicycle with the additional element in the same way as the bicycle
  without that element.)
- The blog post, however, is quite brief. It includes an image which is
  simply a cropped photograph of part of one bicycle pasted beside a
  cropped photograph of part of another bicycle, together creating a
  kind of chimeric bicycle, all done with clunky,
  beginner-level photo editing. The very brief accompanying text
  basically says "bicycle type X and bicycle type Y are well-known, and
  the usefulness of this part of X and this part of Y are well-known,
  so why don't we see any XY bicycles that are made by simply taking
  this part of X and mashing it up with this part of Y, like I
  illustrated in this photo?"
- The description goes no further; there is no description of the
  relevant parts of X and Y. However, I think a person of ordinary
  skill would easily understand from the very brief text and the image
  how to make the bicycle described in the blog post.
- (In fact, I think even without the blog post giving the brief
  description and illustration, the XY bicycle would be obvious to a
  practitioner of ordinary skill, but my sense is that arguing for
  obviousness would be a riskier path, and unnecessary anyway if there
  is an argument that the blog discloses the XY vehicle.)

**The question is:** how explicit and detailed does this instance of non-patent prior art need to be in order to invalidate the patent?

According to one section of the Manual of Patent Examining Procedure (https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2152.html#ch2100_d20033_1da60_2e9), the prior art document must disclose every element of the claim "explicitly or inherently", “arranged or combined in the same way as in the claim", and it must enable the person of ordinary skill to make the invention "without undue experimentation."

This reference from the MPEP seems encouraging: while the blog post doesn't explicitly list the various elements of X and Y, those elements are inherent in X and Y, I think.

Another encouraging reference from another section of the manual (https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2164.html#d0e215634) says that the amount of guidance needed to enable the invention is low in "predictable arts", like bicycle inventions.

Based on my reading of those references from the manual, it seems that the blog post describing the bicycle, though it contains only a very brief description and a rudimentary illustration, would be sufficiently enabling.

Am I on the right track, or am I missing something crucial?

And, not that I want to get too much deeper into this, but can anyone recommend any brief discussions of relevant cases (ideally, in a "predictable art") where non-patent prior art that contained relatively brief description was considered sufficiently enabling to invalidate a patent claim?

Comment: If the patent has expired, why are you worried? Once a patent expires, anyone can use the invention described by its claims free of charge.

Comment: It's an unexpired patent, not an expired one—I guess that was an awkward choice of wording, I should have said "active".

Comment: A difference in treatment between a patent as prior art and a non-patent reference as prior art is that a patent (expired or not) is presumed to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

> (Note: the blog post is not cited in the patent or its examination.)

This gives the added advantage as the same has not been examined the page could be a potential Novelty destroyer for the patent.

> how explicit and detailed does this instance of non-patent prior art need to be in order to invalidate the patent?

The actual scenario would differ case by case. If the prior art describes the same invention from the blog apart from the minor improvements then, please look into the claims. Are the claims scope limited for the minor improvement because the minor improvements ? as such improvements are always patentable.

As for you question how detailed the prior art must disclose depends on An ordinary person skilled in the art (POSA), upon reading the blog could arrive at such invention under any of the two categories.

1. can such improvement be anticipated based on that blog post (does the post describes the invention within the four corners of the page)
2. Is it obvious for a POSA to arrive at that invention upon combination of blog with some other document (Eg: The blog describes a cycle without suspension and there is Moped with suspension. To improve the comfort of the cycle ride combining the suspension of moped with cycle to improve would have been obvious as the same is achieved when used in cycle or moped)

In brief the prior alone (blog) alone or in combination with some other document could it be possible for a person skilled in the art to arrive at that invention is the factor that has to be considered in evaluating the prior art.